# Which of these ESC circuits is better for controlling four coreless brushed motors?

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, motor, brushed-dc-motor

I am building a small brushed quad rotor using the following motors [either one of them]:

- [Motor 1](https://robu.in/product/65mm-blade-propeller-prop-720-cw-ccw-brushed-motor-indoor-racing-drone-quad-copter/)
- [Motor 2](https://robu.in/product/65mm-blade-propeller-prop-615-cw-ccw-coreless-brushed-motor-indoor-racing-drone-quad-copter/)

I am not able to decide for which speed control circuit should I use with it.

I have two options:

**Option A:**

SI2302 MOSFET with flyback diode

[image: SI2302 Mosfet with Flyback Diode]

Using the SI2302 MOSFET, I found this on Electronoobs.com

**Option B:**

DRV8833 (2A/channel)

[image: DRV8833 (2A/channel)]

Using the DRV8833, in which I will use one Channel for each motor. The direction change is not a requirement.

If anyone has some suggestions regarding current rating for the battery preferred for this kind of setup, I will be using a Pico RP2040 for now as the FC.

Comment: only you can decide which circuit is better, because only you know what *better* means